# grep something space something ()

Tags: unix, grep

I want to apologize in advance for my noob question but I want to grep for function headings on c files.  So I am trying to grep newline "^" then some number of spaces " *" then some characters ".*" then some number of spaces " *" then some number of characters again " .*" then some number of spaces again " *" then "(" then some number of characters ".*" then ")".

I tried `grep -E /^( *.*)\2 *\(.*\)/ *.c`
and

```
grep -E /^ *.* *.* *\(.* *.*\*\)/ *.c
                int foo (int bar, double cow)
```

but I don't think ( and ) are supported.  I get back more then I want. How can I grep for function headings like the one above and more.  Again my problem with the above grep is i get back to many results and I get back things that do not have () in them.  I just want function headings.  Thank you for any and all help.

Comment: Are you doing this for code review or tagging? In that case you might want to try ctags, which does this, and a lot more. It also interfaces with many editors and IDEs.

Comment: Its part of a homework assignment and I need to grab function headings out of the c files so I can have a header file with all function declarations.

Comment: Okay. Keep in mind that multiline function definitions will be practially impossible using grep which only does single-line matches afaik. Maybe look into perl regexes.

Comment: Ok what if I use sed's N to append lines from ( to )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does this work for your requirement?

```
grep -P "^\s*[\w ]+\([^\)]*\)"
```

Comment: This does work but it returns for loops and other stuff with () like printf(bla, bla).  I thought by requiring newline something space something that would narrow it down to just function headings.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `egrep '^[ \t]*[^ \t]*[ \t]*[^ \t]*[ \t]*[(][^ \t]*[)]' *.c`

BTW: I discourage the use of shortcuts for whitespace as it is implementation specific.

Comment: I get the message:Badly placed ()'s

Comment: Please try with egrep and place the regex in quotes

Comment: I got the same message as before. egrep /^ *[^ ]* *[^ ]* *[(][^ ]*[)] *.c
Badly placed ()'s.

Comment: You need to quote the regex, otherwise the parentheses will be interpreted as shell stuff. Preferrably use single quotes '...'

Comment: Ok well it did get rid of the message but I got nothing as output.

Comment: Then you don't want spaces but whitespace, i.e. space and tabs

Comment: ah I did not know there was a difference between a space and whitespace.